# LINQ Aggregates in Where string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

I am building a where-condition-string dynamically from user inputs to query on an ObjectSet.

So I've got something like:

```
// Filter name
whereConditions.Add("it.Name=@Name");
parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Name", model.Name));
// Filter Bonuspoints
whereConditions.Add("it.CustomerBonusPoint.BonusPoints=@BonusPoints");
parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("BonusPoints", model.BonusPoints));
// Query
db.persons.Where(whereConditions, parameters.ToArray());
```

Which works perfectly even for related objects as you can see above.

But somehow I am not able to use aggregates. This doesn't work:

```
whereConditions.Add("it.CustomerSaleFigures.Sum(x=>x.Turnover)>@Turnover");
parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Turnover", model.Turnover));
```

Am I missing something?
**Any help appreciated!**

Comment: What Type is persons?

Comment: It is of type ObjectSet<T> where T are EntityTypes

Comment: Are you querying to a database of have you loaded the records you want in memory? Not every linq statement can be translated to the appropriate sql. What error are you getting?

Comment: I get the error: The query syntax is not valid. Near term '>'

Comment: When I use e.g. Count() on a referenced collection the error:
'Count' is not a member of 'Transient.collection occurs

Answer (score 0):

The string conditions used by `ObjectQuery` are Entity SQL, not C# Linq.

```
whereConditions.Add(@"
    Sum(
      SELECT Turnover
      FROM NAVIGATE(it.CustomerSaleFigures)
    ) > @Turnover");

parameters.Add(new ObjectParameter("Turnover", model.Turnover));
```

(I'm not sure if `NAVIGATE()` is required)

Alternatively, you could use Linq:

```
IQueryable<Person> query = db.persons;
query = query.Where(c => c.Name == model.Name);
query = query.Where(c => c.CustomerBonusPoint.BonusPoints == model.BonusPoints);
query = query.Where(c => c.CustomerSaleFigures.Sum(sf => sf.Turnover) > model.Turnover);

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Can't get it to work.
(SELECT SUM(f.Turnover) FROM it.CustomerSaleFigures as f) > @Turnover is as close as I get. It returns the error: The argument types 'Transient.collection[Transient.rowtype[(_##groupAggSum4,Edm.Decimal(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=,Scale=))](Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]' and 'Edm.Decimal' are incompatible for this operation.